# Error when running glm

Tags: r

I'm running a glm in R with the car package and got the following error message:

```
> dlmod = glm(dlstatus ~ dlour_bid, data=dlmydat, family=binomial(link="logit"))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
```

My response variable is coded 1/2 and not 0/1.
I'm just not sure how to change this.

```
tat <- dldat$status
dlstatus <- NA
dlstatus[stat %in% levels(stat)[1:2]] <- "Won"
dlstatus[stat %in% levels(stat)[3]] <- "Lost"
dlstatus <- factor(status)
levels(dlstatus)
dlstatus = as.numeric(dlstatus)
dlstatus
```

Can anyone help with changing the labels from 1/2 to 0/1 so that I can run a glm in R.R

EDIT:

Works fine when I factor dlstatus in the flm command.

Thanks and apologies for the kinda stupid question.

Feel free to close.

Comment: No problem. We wouldn't close this ourselves, but if you want to, you could delete it. I don't think anyone would mind, since answering it didn't take much time.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're very close. As the final step, how about just subtracting 1?

```
dlstatus <- dlstatus - 1
```